Create ILogger<T> using c# class name for xUnit Service class initialization
I have a large project with hundreds of c# class files. Need to write xUnit tests for services' functions which depend on many arguments and there may be dependencies of these classes on one another. In some cases the constructor requires ILogger<T>. It's time-taking to initialize those dependencies to run the tests.
Is there a way, to create ILogger<T> based on class name which is obtained thru reflection of parameters?
1 - Get parameters required
public static object CreateInstance(Type type, Assembly[] assemblies)
{
    try
    {
        var constructor = type.GetConstructors().FirstOrDefault();
        if (constructor == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"No public constructor found for type {type.FullName}");
        }

        var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
        var parameterInstances = parameters.Select(p => ResolveDependency(p.ParameterType, assemblies)).ToArray();

        return constructor.Invoke(parameterInstances);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

2 - Resolve dependencies
private static object ResolveDependency(Type type, Assembly[] assemblies)
{
    if (type.Name.IndexOf("IMapper") > -1)
    {
        return AutoMapperConfig.GetMapper();
    }

    if (type.Name.IndexOf("ILogger") > -1)
    {
        try
        {
            var typeArg = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var entityType = FindTypeByName(typeArg.Name, assemblies);                    
            return LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<entityType.GetType()>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
    {
        var implementationType = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => type.IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract);
        if (implementationType != null)
        {
            return CreateInstance(implementationType, assemblies);
        }
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException($"No implementation found for type {type.FullName}");
}

3 - Logger instance - fails
public static object CreateILogger(Type type)
{            
    var genericType = typeof(Logger<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
}

My objective is that for each service class I would call
var myService = ServiceInitializer.Initialize(MyService);

The underlying function "Initialize" will gather required parameters and itirate down to last one and initialize those. I am explicitly ignoring all DLLs except those which are written by us.
May be I have choosen wrong approach to write XUnit tests, your suggestions are much needed just keep in view that I want to get rid of initializing n number of classes for one service to be tested.

why don't you use a mocking framework?

I am using mock;  DbContext, DbSet, & repositories are mocked with test data, and those services which are needed but not required by the functions being tested are mocked. However, some functions' class constructor may need ILogger.
To create something var _logger = Mock<ILogger<TypeName>>(), I must know it beforehand, which I do not want to because it may be requried for 'n' number of dependencies. Is there a way to achieve it?

That doesn’t sound like a unit test

If I got you right, there are already libraries doing the work for you :)
Let's consider sample setup:
public interface IService1 { }
public class Service1 : IService1 { }
public interface IService2 { }
public class Service2 : IService2 { }

public class Sut 
{
    private readonly IService1 service1;
    private readonly IService2 service2;

    public Sut(IService1 service1, IService2 service2)
    {
        this.service1 = service1;
        this.service2 = service2;
    }
};

Then, if you want to test Sut, but don't care about dependencies (that what good practice is), then you just need to mock those.
You could start creating Mock<> objects, but that would be again cumbersome. But there are nuget packages:

AutoFixture
AutoFixture.AutoMoq

They allow "auto-magic" creation of objects. Example usage in unit test with comments:
public class UnitTest1
{
    // Here AutoMoqCustomization enables Fixture to create 
    // mocks of interfaces.
    private readonly IFixture _fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        // Will automatically crweate Sut object and pass
        // mockaed interfaces to constructor
        var sut = _fixture.Create<Sut>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test2()
    {
        // Here you instruct Fixture to use object provided 
        // for a given interface. Now whenever IService1 is
        // needed, Fixture will pass our object.
        _fixture.Inject<IService1>(new Service1());
        var sut = _fixture.Create<Sut>();
    }
}


Yes, you are right, I ended up using Mock for all and Mock.Setup where needed.

@user3104116 If my answer was helpful, you should accept/upvote it
